# Adding a list of multiple new rows to python dataframe without looping through

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a corpus as follows

**Col1   |  Col2 |   Col3  |   Col4**

```
A       B      C         D
D       G      H         F
I       K      P         Q
L       M      N         P
```

The intent is to create bigrams on each column and create single column python dataframe as follows

(A,D)

(D,I)

(I,L)

(B,G)

(G,H)

I am looping through each of the columns and created a bigram list for each column. How do I add them to the dataframe. I want to avoid looping through this list for performance

```
txn_corpus_pair=pd.DataFrame(columns=['bigram'])

for i in range(0, txn_count):
    bigram_firstitem=txn_corpus.iloc[0:,i]
    bigram_seconditem=txn_corpus.iloc[1:,i]
    bigram_list=list(zip(bigram_firstitem,bigram_seconditem))
```

Now the bigram list is ready for each column. When I try to append all these rows in a single shot

`txn_corpus_pair=txn_corpus_pair.append(bigram_list,ignore_index=True)`

It reads the bigram_list as 2 separate columns- and reports an error. I can loop through the list and append rowwise, but that would be very inefficient. Need help on appending the fulllist

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you just need to nest your pairs within another list so that the dataframe doesn't try to move them to separate columns.

```
ls = [(1, 2) for _ in range(100)]
print(pd.DataFrame(ls))
# This produces two columns

ls = [[(1, 2)] for _ in range(100)]
print(pd.DataFrame(ls))
# This produces one column
```

Comment: I tried this- this converts the bigrams in each column into new rows. So if I had 20 bigrams created in each original column and I had 10 original columns, I will end up with a dataframe that has 10 rows and 20 columns.

Comment: I guess I'm confused about the data format you are expecting out of this program. In the post example you start with four columns and produce 12 bigrams (3 per column). Do you then want one new column for all 12 bigrams? Do you want bigrams added onto the existing columns?

Comment: I apologize for any confusion- I was looking to get all the bigrams in a single column. MY actual datset has around 100 columns with around 10,000 rows. This would lead to around 9999 bigrams per original column. My endstate would be a single column having 9999*100 rows

Comment: I think I understand now. You call append several times right? Can you instead make one large bigram_list that holds them all and just append once? (While having the nested list to keep them as pairs). Instead of append you can also try: txn_corpus_pair['col5'] = bigram_list

Comment: how- I am doing each column separately to avoid combining last row if column1 with first row of column 2 etc...

Comment: before for loop: bigram_list = [],

during for loop:  bigram_list ***+=*** list(zip(bigram_firstitem,bigram_seconditem)). The += adds like [1, 2, 3] + [4, 5] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237946/discussion-between-raghu-and-mandias).